# Copy and paste below the yellow highlighted row

Tags: excel, vba, header

Not sure if this is a possibility but here goes.  I'm at a standstill for this vba code.  I tried attaching a picture example - not sure if it'll show up correctly.

*Everything in blue font, I have created a vba code to copy it directly from the top rows down*

1) I need a macro that would look in all the cells in the header row 1 for "Cont Type" and if it finds in it any cell, then in the same column directly below the yellow highlighted row (in this case, it's row 5 but it could change because the data will be updated daily), put in the word "Finance" and the word "Finance" has to go all the way down to match the number of rows in column A.

click on the link to see example of what I'm trying to accomplish
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HmwN.png)

Comment: *"I need a macro"* means you will have to write that macro. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a loop to do so.  So something like this:

```
x = 1 'the starting column to look for content type
Do While cells(1, x) <> "" 'look in every column until your columns are empty
If Cells(1, x) = "Cont Type" Then
Range(Cells(6, x), Cells(n, x)) = "Finance" 'With n equaling your last column to insert this to
Else
End If
x = x + 1 'go to the next column to look
Loop
```

Comment: Hi there! I really appreciate this macro you provided but it didn't work and kept getting stuck on this line: Range(Cells(6, x), Cells(n, x)) = "Finance".  I think I might run into the same issue with the other vba because the issue I had was the yellow highlighted row is always changing depending on the data I receive daily. The macro has to find the words" cont type" first in the header row and then add the word "finance" below the yellow highlighted row. For today the yellow row is on row 75

Comment: Right so you'll need to make the range Range(Cells(75, x)….  what error did you receive?  worked for  me when I ran it.

Comment: Hi, I changed as you suggested and it gave the error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".  Would I always have to change the row number in the macro every time I run it?  What if tomorrow, the row is 90?

Comment: you'll have to set something so it knows dynamically what row to use.  Why 90?  Why 75?  what drives that row number?  Based on that, you would set another variable (y) equal to what the row 'should be'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastColumn As Long, i As Long

    'Change sheet name if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find LastColumn of row 1
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'Loop Cells of the first row
        For i = 1 To LastColumn

            'If cells in row 1 and column i is "Cont Type"
            If .Cells(1, i).Value = "Cont Type" Then
                'Import in range
                .Range(.Cells(6, i), .Cells(9, i)).Value = "Finance"
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Hi there!  I really appreciate this macro you provided but it didn't work because the issue I had was the yellow highlighted row is always changing depending on the data I receive daily.  The macro has to find the yellow highlighted row and put in the word "Finance" below it.  For today the yellow row is on row 75.

Comment: The yellow row is the line after tha lastdata?

Comment: HI, the yellow row was the last row of the original data but then I added a macro to copy everything (original data) from columns A-L (minus the header) and paste in the first empty cell (column A) below the data.